# Unable to sign in to apps with Gmail in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, gmail

When I try to log in into certain apps using gmail I get errors.

For example when I try to logging in to 'Blogg' app which is for blogspot it says

```
You are not connected to the internet
```

Could it be due to `Two factor Authentication`? I have also tried using one time password but it does not work.

Comment: @Ramhound I have already said that one-time-password did not work. You can try for yourself if you have time, the application is free.

Comment: my application specific password works for me.. make sure you are copying it right...

Comment: @Kang - I could have sworn when I read your question you didn't mention that fact.  The reason I mentioned using the application specific application is because of the dozens of other questions that made a point of saying using it fixed this problem.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't edit this post.

Answer (score 1):

My first (and only) suggestion would be to download the [Microsoft Accounts troubleshooter](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/4/F24D0C03-4181-4E5B-A23B-5C3A6B5974E3/microsoftaccounts.diagcab). It diagnosis and attempts to fix the following issues:

- Corrupt Microsoft Account settings
- Can’t connect to the sync service
- Problems with Microsoft account Policy
- Microsoft Account required
- Connection issues due to proxy or certificate issues
- Check for roaming GPO enabled status
- Problem with system registration
- Signed in with a guest account, or Roaming User Profiles enabled
- **You are not connected to the Internet**
- Proxy Settings
- You have reached your daily sync quote
- Sync your settings is turned off
- Check system not activated.

See [Windows 8: Troubleshoot Microsoft Accounts Issues](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/07/04/windows-8-troubleshoot-microsoft-accounts-issues/) for additional information.

Comment: This did seem to take me one step ahead. But I am still getting the same error.